# Can't access hidden worksheet tabs in excel with Powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a few excel work books with hidden worksheet tabs in them.  I want those tabs to remain hidden, but I also want to access them with a PowerShell script.  However, my script seems to ignore those worksheets hidden in excel.  I have looked into the com objects and cant seem to find a property for this.  I have tried using $excel.visible = $true, but that seems to be entirely separate plus items that are not visible are still accessible by Powershell usually.  I want to know if there is a way to programatically access these hidden tabs.  If I need to make them visible then invisible again that would work, but I want them to remain hidden normally.  Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
cd "P:\ANG_System_Files"

function Add-MissingVendor
{
    param([PSCustomObject]$TypeOfVendors, [string]$excel_file_path)

    $standardDifferences = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $TypeOfVendors.VendorName -DifferenceObject $MainVendors.VendorName -PassThru
    foreach ($difference in $standardDifferences)
    {
        $Excel1 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $ExcelWorkBookMain  = $Excel1.Workbooks.Open("P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\Vendors.xlsx")
        $ExcelWorkSheetMain = $ExcelWorkBookMain.WorkSheets.item("VendorList")
        $ExcelWorkSheetMain.activate() | Out-Null
        $ExcelWorkSheetMain.Visible = $true

        $Found = $ExcelWorkSheetMain.Cells.Find($difference)
        $foundDifference = $ExcelWorkSheetMain.Rows($($Found.Row))

        $Excel2 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $ExcelWorkBookUpdate = $Excel2.Workbooks.Open($excel_file_path)
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate = $ExcelWorkBookUpdate.WorkSheets.item("VendorList")
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.activate() | Out-Null
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Visible = $true

        $vendorName      = $($foundDifference.Cells[1].Value2)
        $contactName     = $($foundDifference.Cells[2].Value2)
        $vendorAddress   = $($foundDifference.Cells[3].Value2)
        $vendorCityState = $($foundDifference.Cells[4].Value2)
        $vendorPhone     = $($foundDifference.Cells[5].Value2)
        $vendorEmail     = $($foundDifference.Cells[6].Value2)

        $row = $($Excel2.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows)[-1].Row + 1
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,1) = $vendorName     
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,2) = $contactName    
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,3) = $vendorAddress  
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,4) = $vendorCityState
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,5) = $vendorPhone    
        $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Cells.Item($row,6) = $vendorEmail    

        $sortRange = $ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.UsedRange
        $sortRange.Sort

        $ExcelWorkBookUpdate.Save()

        $ExcelWorkBookUpdate.Close()
        $ExcelWorkBookMain.Close()
        $Excel1.Quit()
        $Excel2.Quit()

        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel1)
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel2)
    }
}

$MainVendors     = (Import-Excel -Path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\Vendors.xlsx" -WorksheetName "VendorList")
$StandardVendors = (Import-Excel -Path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGstandardPO form-master.xlsx" -WorksheetName "VendorList")
$GlassVendors    = (Import-Excel -Path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGglassPO form-master.xlsx" -WorksheetName "VendorList")
$ViraconVendors  = (Import-Excel -Path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGviraconPO form-master.xlsx" -WorksheetName "VendorList")

Add-MissingVendor -TypeOfVendor $StandardVendors -excel_file_path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGstandardPO form-master.xlsx"
Add-MissingVendor -TypeOfVendor $GlassVendors    -excel_file_path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGglassPO form-master.xlsx"
Add-MissingVendor -TypeOfVendor $ViraconVendors  -excel_file_path "P:\ANG_System_Files\commonFormsUsedInScripts\ANGviraconPO form-master.xlsx"
```

Comment: Is the "VendorList" the hidden worksheet you are trying to work with? If not what is the name of the hidden worksheet?

Comment: Yes the vendor list is the hidden worksheet.

Comment: I think your issue is somewhere else other than the worksheet being hidden. The lines "$ExcelWorkSheetMain.Visible = $true" and "$ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Visible = $true" is making the worksheets visible/unhidden. Incidentally you are also saving the workbook "$ExcelWorkBookUpdate" with the worksheet still visible/unhidden, you should add "$ExcelWorkSheetUpdate.Visible = $false" just before "$ExcelWorkBookUpdate.Save()" to make the worksheet hidden prior to saving.   Are you able to upload some sample data so that this could be investigated into further?

Comment: Sorry for the late response CraftyB.  I ended up using a completely different work around for the issue.  My boss expressed a desire to use a completely separate excel sheet so this ceased to be an issue, but I thank you for the help.